# what to use for identifying between clients that connect to a server? Java, Android, Sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am working with a Java desktop server and multiple Android clients connected to it.  on the server side I need to identify which client has sent me a message by sockets TCP/IP and send a response only to that one client and not the others.

I will store all the sockets of clients in an ArrayList.

first here are two ways that I tried that don't work;

-- the IP address of the client, get this by calling socket.getLocalSocketAddress() in the client and socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() in the server,  but they never match. for example i got in the client XXX.XXX.11.17 and in the server XXX.XXX.0.13, they are supposed to be the same for the same connection.

-- the port number,  get this by calling getLocalPort() in the client and getPort() in the server, yes this works perfectly and the numbers match so I can use this, HOWEVER there is a possibility that the randomly selected port numbers on two different clients could be the same.  not likely but possible. so that means there is no guarentee that they are unique.

what is the alternative that I can use that will work?

Comment: There are 2 instance of my client application working on Same IP and port. How do I identify request from each client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> getLocalSocketAddress() in the client and getRemoteSocketAddress() in the server [...] are supposed to be the same for the same connection.

No, because you don't know what's in between. Most mobile providers use proxies, NAT and so on. The mobile device thinks it's on a LAN (10.0.0.x or 192.168.x.x addresses) which the provider provides. It's even possible for multiple clients to have the same remote address (as seen from your server).

That being said, you can uniquely identify a client in your server application by the remote IP address and port combined together, given the server listens on one IP, port and protocol. This information is available from `socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()`, where the returned `InetSocketAddress` (in case of an internet socket) contains both the remote IP and port (`getAddress()` and `getPort()` respectively).

But as indicated by the other answer, you don't really need a way to *identify* a client. A network client *is* identified by the socket you receive data on (a socket is an exclusive connection between two nodes), so just send the data back to the socket that you received the request on.

If you do need more bookkeeping data about the connected client, wrap the client socket in a wrapper class that contains additional information.

Comment: It isn't possible for many clients to have the same remote `SocketAddress`, as it includes the source port, and the rules of TCP require that the tuple *{source IP, source port, target IP, target port}* be unique.

Comment: @EJP I have clarified my answer, please consider revising the vote. Thanks for the feedback anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to identify which client has sent me a message by sockets TCP/IP and send a response only to that one client and not the others.

Send it back down the same socket you received the request from.

If you need a permanent identified for the client, you can use the result of `Socket.getRemoteAddress()`.